# Finite fields and arithmetic

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

For every prime number $p$ and every positive integer $k$, there is a field with exactly $p^k$ elements.  When $k=1$, it's just the integers$\bmod p^k$, and when $k>1$, it's not.  So if I want the elements of the field to be the congruence classes$\bmod p^k$, then the addition and multiplication will differ from adding and multiplying$\bmod p^k$.  Is there any way to define addition and multiplication on those classes that makes them a field and interacts in some elegant way with the usual arithmetic operations?

Comment: I find it somewhat concerning that the elements $p$, $p^{2}$, $p^3$, ... , $p^{k-1}$ are markedly different from the other elements - but I guess that makes this question all the more tantalizing to see how that fits into finite groups (if there is an answer)

Comment: If you're talking about _groups_, maybe we should remember that the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic.  How will that get involved? BTW, notice the typographical difference between $p,p^2,p^3,$...,$p^{k-1}$ and $p,p^2,p^3,\ldots,p^{k-1}$.  This is quite conspicuous in actual LaTeX, just as it is in MathJax, which is used here.  The latter form is considered correct. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I feel it somewhat unclear what sort of properties of the usual arithmetic you would want to preserve. The usual addition gives a cyclic group, whereas the addition in the field is the other extreme (elementary abelian). And the usual multiplication will have several zero-divisors.

Comment: OK, let's think about $7^2$.  Suppose you express $0,1,2,\ldots,48$ in base $7$.  In normal addition$\bmod49$ with base $7$ numerals, if you have $(25+14)_{\text{SEVEN}}$, You'd first add the units digits $5+4=12$ and you get $2$ as the units digit and _carry_ the $1$.  So let's just do it _without carrying_.  Then you have the set $\{0,1,2,\ldots,48\}$ with the addition-without-carrying operation isomorphic to the addition in the field with $49$ elements.  Then the problem is whether something other than the usual multiplication but interacting with it in some interesting way will serve.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, for $k>1$ (and even for $k=1$ but in this case you'll have the same result) you could construct a field $K$ of charateristic $p$ with $p^k$ elements. As $\mathbf{Z} / p^k$ has also $p^k$ elements, it is in bijection via a map $\varphi : \mathbf{Z} / p^k \rightarrow K$ with $K$. (Note that $\varphi$ cannot be a morphism of ring if $k>1$ because $p$ is a zero divisor in $\mathbf{Z} / p^k$ but not in $K$). Now for $x,y\in \mathbf{Z} / p^k$ define $x +^\varphi y := \varphi^{-1} (\varphi(x) + \varphi(y))$ and $x {\times}^{\varphi} y := \varphi^{-1} (\varphi(x) \times \varphi(y))$. If $0^{\varphi}$ and $1^{\varphi}$ correspond to $0$ and $1$ via $\varphi$ then $\left( \mathbf{Z} / p^k, +^\varphi, \times^\varphi, 0^\varphi, 1^\varphi \right)$ will be a field, isomorphic to $K$.

Now your/the question is, could we find a $\varphi$ such that the additive law $+^\varphi$ is equal to the canonical additive law $+$ (the one coming from $\mathbf{Z}$) on $\mathbf{Z} / p^k$ ? The answer is no. Because, as in $\mathbf{Z}$, the additive law determines uniquely the multiplicative law. Indeed $$k \times l = \underbrace{l + \ldots + l}_{\textrm{$k$ times}} = \underbrace{1 + \ldots + 1}_{\textrm{$k l$ times}}$$

Comment: You're carefully proving what my posted question already said more tersely.  But the question at the end was "Is there any way to define addition and multiplication on those classes that makes them a field and interacts in some elegant way with the usual arithmetic operations?".  I can't see that you've addressed that. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I see you edited my question to remplace in powers {\varphi} by \varphi, which is fondamentally *very* useful. Was just to be able to say you've edited it or ? Anyway.

Regarding your interesting question : arithmetic is merely defined by inclusion and sum of ideals, which requires addition first and then multiplication. So you need at least to have the usual + on $\mathbf{Z}/ p^k$, and I showed that if you have this, you also have multiplication, which leads as observed to a contradiction.

Comment: There is up to isomorphism one field of order $p^k$, namely the splitting field of $x^{p^k}-x$. So the cardinality basically defines the operations.

Comment: @RobertGreen : I'm not following the reasoning leading to your assertion that "you need at least to have the usual $+$ on $\mathbb Z/p^k$".  Certainly you need that if you want an isomorphism with $\mathbb Z/p^k$ with its usual addition$\bmod p^k$, but in my posted question I've already rejected that.  Take a look at my new comment under the question, about addition without carrying. ${}\quad{}$

Comment: As for my edit, the reason it ended up the way it did is that I decided after hesitating to leave \ldots intact instead of changing it to \cdots.  If I'd seen something like $1+$...$+1$ (I see things like that here all the time) instead of $1+\ldots+1$, I would of course have changed it, probably to $1+\cdots+1$.  I am inclined to suspect that you really don't know the reason for my changing +^{\varphi} to +^\varphi, and I hesitate to get into that since it's a somewhat different topic and might get lengthy. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You need it if you want *interaction in some elegant way with the usual arithmetic operations*, to quote you.

Comment: So then you consider it self-evident that my addition-without-carrying suggestion is inelegant? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @RobertGreen : Apparently you construed "interacts in some elegant way with the usual arithmetic operations" as meaning that the addition would actually have to _be_ the usual addition.  But I don't think my words can reasonably be take to mean that. ${}\qquad{}$